# Is there a way to extract the line number of an object from an R script?

Tags: r

I am writing some documentation for a shiny app in markdown, and I want to provide a dynamic line number in the script where an object or function is defined. For example, if I wanted to know the line number for `x`, that would be line `2`.

```
1  library(tidyverse)
2  x <- data(iris)
```

And I would like this to change if new code is entered to change the line number. Is this even possible? I found some similar questions that involved `traceback()` and `findLineNum()`, but that seems to be only for errors and debugging, and doesn't return line numbers.

Comment: Does it answer your question: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/number-lines.html? If you are using quarto to write documentation, there is very similar approach: https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html#line-numbers

Comment: Beautiful! I just may be able to make that work. Thanks so much for your help!